# Any way to get the pending_ms value for the current (or a specific) request from App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'd like to know, in a particular request, what the pending_ms value is (assuming it exists for the given request).

I know that the App Engine logs include this value, but I'm hoping to find it elsewhere for use in gae_mini_profiler.

I've searched around the App Engine source, but no luck -- this is being added elsewhere in the GAE pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not currently any way to access this programmatically, either from within the request or outside it. Please do file a feature request for it, though.